# Call MapActivity to MainActivity with markers android

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment

I have a MapActivity (The default by Android) and a MainActivity. And i call the MapActivity with an include like this at the MainActivity:

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/mapa"
    layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>
```

It shows me the map but not the markers anyone knows why? In the MapActivity i have this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Use this only dont call include layout it wont work properly

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />
```

Comment: I did it and it doesn't show the markers and the map now